# Ruby: using self in blocks?

Tags: ruby

Short question: when calling a method of an object "a" and passing it a block, can I access "a" from within that block?

Example: Let's say I have an array "words" and I first want to remove all the "bad" words from it (determined using a function) and then find the word that is most frequent among those that remained. I can do it in two lines:

```
temp_words = words.reject{|w| word_is_bad(w)}
puts temp_words.max{|w| temp_words.count(w)}
```

However, I wish to avoid having to create a new variable called "temp_words" and do everything in one line, like this:

```
words.reject{|w| word_is_bad(w)}.max{|w| self.count(w)}
```

even though I believe my intention is clear, the code fails since "self" does not refer to the temp array generated after reject is called, but to the program's main object.

Comment: The short answer is no, not without using instance_eval or something similar.  You don't really need to chain the blocks though.  Could always write it like `words.max_by {|w| word_is_bad(w) ? -1 : words.count(w) }` (side note, I think you probably want max_by rather than max)

Comment: @numbers1311407 That would be an excellent answer, Why not add it as one?

Comment: @MarkThomas good point, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to your way of doing it, you can write:

```
words.reject{|w| word_is_bad(w)}.instance_eval{max_by{|w| count(w)}}
```

but a better and more popular way to do it is:

```
words.reject{|w| word_is_bad(w)}.group_by{|w| w}.max_by{|_, a| a.length}.first
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, not without using instance_eval or something similar.

You don't really need to chain the blocks though. Could always write it like:

```
 words.max_by {|w| word_is_bad(w) ? -1 : words.count(w) }
```

(side note, I think you probably want max_by rather than max)

If you find yourself having to get clever with one liners to express your logic, it might make sense to encapsulate what you need in a class.  Consider this simple example:

```
class Words < Array
  def self.is_bad(word)
    foo
  end

  def good
    reject {|w| Word.is_bad(w) }
  end
end
```

Which would allow you to write:

```
words = Words.new(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
words.good.max_by {|word| words.count(word) }
```

Much more expressive and sidesteps the problem.

A step further:

```
def max_good
  good.max_by {|word| count(word) }
end
```

And you could write simply `words.max_good`

Comment: This is a good solution, but only for the example. In my "real" problem, the temp array I'm working on is a result of a much more complicated process.

Comment: When all words are bad words, this code silently returns the first word without telling it is bad.

Comment: You may want to extend `Array` or otherwise write a custom enumerable `Words` class to encapsulate the logic you need.

Comment: @sawa That's true, so rejecting first does make more sense if this were to be a one liner.  Given that the OP has admitted the "real" problem is more complicated it probably makes sense to circumvent tricky one liners all together and encapsulate the logic in a class.